# google maps api total distance calculation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The following code, calculates the total route of the journey, and displays the result in kilometers:

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        var total = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
          total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        }
        total = total / 1000.
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
```

Instead of kilometeres I need to display the total distance in miles. What I need is the formula to calculate into miles. I have searched for it, but I have hit a dead end, Anyone have any help on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1.0 km per 0.621371 mile (from google)](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=miles+per+km&oq=miles+per+km)